# How to fix ‘404--Not Found' issue of Spring Web Application

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

I migrated Spring XML base configuration, REST service application into Java base configuration. After the migration was done, the application worked well on **Apache Tomcat 8** server. But it didn't work on **WebLogic Server 12** in version 12.1.3.0.0 and deployment happened without any error.

I removed web.xml file. I added weblogic.xml file into WEB-INF, configuration below:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends ABCInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws 
    ServletException {
        init(servletContext);
    }
}

class ABCInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    public void init(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new 
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(WebConfig.class);

        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = 
        container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

Expected Result : The endpoints work well.

Actual Result   :

> Error 404--Not Found
>                     From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
>                     10.4.5 404 Not Found

Please anyone help me understand this problem.?

Comment: Did you check the many other 404 spring issues on SO?

Comment: @jasie  .Yes, I checked many other issues related to this. But, I couldn't find out a solution.

Comment: It would help a lot if you added to your question which proposed solutions/fixes you tried.

Comment: @jasie . Thank you very much for your help. The error happened due to version incompatibility. I redeployed the application on higher version of weblogic server.
It's working now.

Comment: Congrats! In suggest you edit the answer you got and turn it into a real answer :-)

Comment: @jasie . Sure, I'll do :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please check on a higher version of weblogic server, seems there is a
>   incompatibility of spring version and weblogic release ,

Answer :
I tried a sample with same spring configuration and it works perfectly with Spring 4.2.6 (version doesnt matter , 4.1.x > ) , and weblogic server you mentioned ( not the minimal or portable version ).Besides,if you have made any swagger configuration on the application please check the compatibility of the swagger version.

Comment: This is not an answer, this should be a comment. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Thilanka A. Weerasinghe , It worked on higher version of weblogic server. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @jasie , yes it is not , this was just suggested to verify whether there are any issues on the application level when deploying to weblogic , i m still unable to comment due to lack of reputation points .

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows 2016 server to deploy your application, it is incompatible with the Weblogic 12.1.x. Try upgrading the weblogic version in your application. Also consider upgrading to Java 8 if you are not using it in your project. Weblogic 12.2.x and Java 8 shoud go together.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Senthil.